# Se puede obtener una lista de los procesos actuales corriendo en el PC con python

Tags: python

quiero saber si hay alguna forma de saber que procesos están corriendo tanto en primer como segundo plano en Python claro si es posible me seria de mucha ayuda gracias.

Comment: Esto en SO (sitio en ingles) responde a tu pregunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632234/list-running-processes-on-64-bit-windows. La verdad, puede que la respuesta a tu pregunta dependa del sistema operativo, podrías agregar cual es el sistema operativo en el cual quieres hacer eso por favor?

Comment: MicroPython corre en microprocesadores sin S.O.; no hay una "lista de procesos".

Comment: El sistema para el que planeo usarlo es Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor solucion para que el script sea pequeño ya que es una herramienta de productividad y para que sea facil de editar decidi usa [WMI](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html)

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()

for process in c.Win32_Process():
  print (process.Name)
```

Comment: ¿Qué procesos muestra? ¿Todos, sólo los propios?